# SQL multiple combine where statements

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I'm looking to combine two different where statements and get an output when both situations occur.

```
 SELECT j.project_id Matter_Primary_Key,

   j.type_id,
   l.name Role,
   l.Tree_position,
   j.user_id User_Primary_Key,
   y.username,
   tcont.name || ',' || tcont.first_name Assignee_Name,
   j.assigned_on,
   j.unassigned_on,
   tproj.number_string Matter_Number,
   tproj.name Plan_Name
 FROM j_proj_assignee j,

   y_user y,
   l_proj_assignee_type l,
   t_project tproj,
   t_contact tcont
WHERE     j.unassigned_on IS NULL

   AND (j.type_id = '93' AND y.username = 'XXX')
   AND (j.type_id = '3010' AND y.username = 'YYY')
   AND j.type_id = l.primary_key
   AND j.user_id = y.primary_key
   AND j.project_id = tproj.primary_key
   AND y.contact_id = tcont.primary_key
```

But I'm having issues with my query inside the () since they're pulling from two different tables, but I only want the records where both those situations apply. Do I need to a join statement?

Comment: You probably want an OR between the two bracketed conditions

Comment: Also, *do I need to do a Join* -- you are already joining the tables using an older syntax. Always use explicit join syntax.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines read like you are requiring all of the terms specified at the same time. For example, the type_id can not be 93 and also 3010 at the same time.

```
   AND (j.type_id = '93' AND y.username = 'XXX')
   AND (j.type_id = '3010' AND y.username = 'YYY')
```

Instead, try something like this to see if it works:

```
   AND ((j.type_id = '93' AND y.username = 'XXX') OR (j.type_id = '3010' AND y.username = 'YYY'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I need to be able to get both results combined together and not either or

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how you are intending to join then. The way it is currently specified, you will have only one j.type_id for each row - so I would expect your query to return nothing. How can there be more than one j.type_id?

Comment: wouldn't using OR like @dimab0 mentioned combine the results together?